# Is it true that $\gcd(s(p^k), D(p^k)) = 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the sum of divisors of a positive integer $x$.

Define
$$s(x):=\sigma(x)-x$$
to be the [sum of the aliquot divisors](http://oeis.org/A001065) of $x$, and define
$$D(x):=2x-\sigma(x)$$
to be the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $x$.

Now, let $p$ be a prime number, and let $k$ be a positive integer.

Here is my question:

> Is it true that $\gcd(s(p^k), D(p^k)) = 1$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

If $k=1$, then $s(p^k)=s(p)=\sigma(p)-p=(p+1)-p=1$, so that clearly
$$\gcd(s(p), D(p))=1.$$

Now let $k>1$.  We obtain
$$D(p^k) = 2p^k - \sigma(p^k) = p^k - \bigg(\sigma(p^k) - p^k\bigg) = p^k - s(p^k)$$
so that we get
$$\gcd(s(p^k), D(p^k)) = \gcd(s(p^k), p^k - s(p^k)) = \gcd(s(p^k), p^k)$$
$$= \gcd(\sigma(p^k) - p^k, p^k) = \gcd(\sigma(p^k), p^k) = 1.$$

Note that a proof for the assertion that $\gcd(\sigma(p^k),p^k)=1$ is standard material in undergraduate textbooks on (elementary) number theory. So essentially, I will be assuming this assertion without proof.

> Is this proof correct?

Comment: You only prove that $\gcd(s(p^k),p^k) = 1$ for $k=1$ so your proof is missing to show this (or that $\gcd(\sigma(p^k),p^k) = 1$) for $k>1$

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Winther!  A proof for the assertion that $\gcd(\sigma(p^k),p^k)=1$ is standard material in undergraduate textbooks on (elementary) number theory.  So essentially, I assumed that assertion without proof.

Comment: Let me add the intermediate steps in my proof so that it is clearer.

Comment: Yes I know it's not hard, but I just pointed it out since you did take time to prove it for $k=1$. Because of this the proof just looks like it's missing something.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris  An easier approach is : If some prime factor $q$ divides both $s(p^k)$ and $D(p^k)$ it also divides $s(p^k)+D(p^k)=p^k$, hence we can conclude $q=p$. The rest should be easy.

Comment: @Peter:  I would be interested to learn more about that *easier approach*.  Care to write it out as an actual answer?  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comment, the only prime possibly both dividing $s(p^k)$ and $D(p^k)$ is $p$.

Hence it remains to show that $s(p^k)$ is not divisible by $p$.

$s(p^k)$ is the sum of the divisors of $p^k$ except $p^k$ itself. All the divisors except $1$ are divisible by $p$, hence the sum cannot be divisible by $p$ (The sum consists of $1$ and in the case $k>1$ of other summands divisible by $p$ , in the case $k=1$ , the sum is just $1$). This completes the proof.