# If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number, then $D(p^k)/s(p^k)$ is in lowest terms. Does this contradict $D(p^k)D(m^2)=2s(p^k)s(m^2)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

In what follows, denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.

If $n$ is odd and $\sigma(n)=2n$, then $n$ is called an *odd perfect number*.

Euler showed that a hypothetical odd perfect number $n$, if one exists, must have the so-called *Eulerian form*
$$n = p^k m^2$$
where $p$ is the special prime satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Since $\gcd(p,m)=1$ and the divisor sum function $\sigma()$ is multiplicative, then we have
$$\sigma(p^k)\sigma(m^2)=\sigma(p^k m^2)=\sigma(n)=2n=2p^k m^2.$$

We ultimately get
$$\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))=\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k}=\frac{m^2}{\sigma(p^k)/2}=\frac{D(m^2)}{s(p^k)}=\frac{2s(m^2)}{D(p^k)} \tag{*},$$
where $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$ is the *deficiency* of $x$ and $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$ is the *aliquot sum* of $x$.

We also know that
$$\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))=p\sigma(m^2)-2(p-1)m^2.$$

The question is as is in the title:

> If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number, then $D(p^k)/s(p^k)$ is in lowest terms.  Does this contradict $D(p^k)D(m^2)=2s(p^k)s(m^2)$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

From this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051973), we know that
$$\gcd(D(p^k),s(p^k)) = 1$$
which means that the fraction $D(p^k)/s(p^k)$ is in **lowest terms**.

However, from Equation $(*)$, we obtain
$$D(p^k)D(m^2)=2s(p^k)s(m^2)$$
which means that the fraction
$$\frac{D(p^k)}{s(p^k)}=\frac{2s(m^2)}{D(m^2)}$$
must also be in lowest terms.

This implies that
$$\gcd(2s(m^2),D(m^2))=1$$
which is equivalent to the equation
$$1=\gcd(2s(m^2),D(m^2))=\gcd(2s(m^2)+D(m^2),D(m^2))$$
$$=\gcd(s(m^2)+s(m^2)+D(m^2),D(m^2))$$
$$=\gcd(s(m^2)+m^2,D(m^2))=\gcd(\sigma(m^2),D(m^2)).$$

But
$$1=\gcd(\sigma(m^2),D(m^2))$$
is equivalent to the equation
$$1=\gcd(\sigma(m^2),\sigma(m^2)+D(m^2))=\gcd(\sigma(m^2),2m^2)=\gcd(\sigma(m^2),m^2),$$
since $\sigma(m^2)$ is odd.

But the equation
$$1=\gcd(\sigma(m^2),m^2)=\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k}$$
contradicts the following result of [[Dris, JIS (2012)]](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html): $\sigma(m^2)/p^k \geq 3$.

**CONCLUSION**

*This appears to prove that there are no other perfect numbers, apart from those for which $\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))=1$.*  Notice that *even perfect numbers* $(2^q - 1)\cdot{2^{q-1}}$ (except for $6$) are of the form
$$P^K M^2$$
where $P=2^q - 1$, $K=1$, and $M = 2^{(q-1)/2}$.  Thus, for even perfect numbers, we have
$$\gcd(M^2,\sigma(M^2))=\gcd(2^{q-1},\sigma(2^{q-1}))=\gcd(2^{q-1},2^q - 1) = 1.$$

Comment: To the (quick) downvoter:  Would you mind explaining your vote?  As it currently is, I am totally clueless.  Any form of feedback (hopefully constructive) would go a long way towards improving future questions/posts.

Comment: "we obtain $D(p^k)D(m^2)=2s(p^k)s(m^2)$ which means that the fraction $\dfrac{D(p^k)}{s(p^k)}=\dfrac{2s(m^2)}{D(m^2)}$ must also be in lowest terms" Why? How do you exclude possibilities like $\dfrac 85=\dfrac{24}{15}$ ? If we have $\gcd(D(p^k),s(p^k)) = 1$ and $D(p^k)D(m^2)=2s(p^k)s(m^2)$, then we can say that there is an integer $z$ such that $D(m^2)=zs(p^k)$ and $2s(m^2)=zD(p^k)$, which implies that $\gcd(2s(m^2),D(m^2))=z$. However, I don't think that $z=1$ follows from these only.

Comment: In fact, to use your notation, $z=\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))$! Please write out [your last comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4640208/if-pk-m2-is-an-odd-perfect-number-then-dpk-spk-is-in-lowest-terms?noredirect=1#comment9795297_4640208) as an actual answer so that I may be able to upvote and then accept it, @mathlove! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we obtain $D(p^k)D(m^2)=2s(p^k)s(m^2)$ which means that the fraction $\dfrac{D(p^k)}{s(p^k)}=\dfrac{2s(m^2)}{D(m^2)}$ must also be in lowest terms

Why? How do you exclude possibilities like $\dfrac 85=\dfrac{24}{15}$ ?

If we have $\gcd(D(p^k),s(p^k))=1$ and $D(p^k)D(m^2)=2s(p^k)s(m^2)$, then we can say that there is an integer $z$ such that $D(m^2)=zs(p^k)$ and $2s(m^2)=zD(p^k)$, which implies that $\gcd(2s(m^2),D(m^2))=z$. However, I don't think that $z=1$ follows from these only.